# Refresh page and change ID of the URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make an page with tabbed content. I'm using foundation tabs (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/tabs.php).

I made an link offside the `<dl></dl>` element, and it doesn't work if I use only `<a href="#simple5">`. I tried an javascript to reload the page `<a href="#simple5" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">`, but doesn't work either.

How can I proceed?

Comment: `<a href="#simple5">` will link to an element with id `simple5`, do you have an element like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call JS on click, it is run before the default action. You reload a page without hashtag.

Try to add the ID with JS : `<a href="#" onClick="window.location = '#simple5'; window.location.reload(true);">`

You can also use et function and get the id dynamically.

---

Sorry for my bad english. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually perform `location.reload`. Navigating to a new hash will update the URL without reloading the page. If an element in your DOM has the ID `simple5`, the browser will scroll to that element.

You may also manually look at the hash change event (or repeatedly check the URL for a change, for browsers that doesn't support that event), and perform an action such as switching to a certain tab.

This is if you want your switching between tabs to be reflected in the browser history. If you don't wish to leave markers in browser history, you would instead want to intercept the link click, extract the `href` to use just as an indicator of which tab to show, perform the tab change, and prevent the browser from following the link (so that no actual hash change will occur)